# how to do if and else statements in python lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
user = input("userinput: ")

myList = ["Noah", "Mike"]
for item in list:
    if user == item:
        print("hello {}".format(user))
    else:
        print("invalid")
```

what I am trying to do is if you said something in the list you `get hello (and the name you pick)`

for ex:

```
input: Noah

output: hello Noah
```

And if you do not put any thing in nothing in the list correctly

```
input: Mikee

output: invalid
```

so basically I am asking a more complex if and else statement in python lists

Comment: One error is that the name of your `list` is `myList` so it should be `for item in myList:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over each item in the list and printing its validity. You want to check just once:

```
user = input("userinput: ")

myList = ["Noah", "Mike"]
if user in myList:
    print("hello {}".format(user))
else:
    print("invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user = input("userinput: ")

myList = ["Noah", "Mike"]

if user in myList:
    print("hello {}".format(user))
else:
    print("invalid")
```

you need to just check that value is exist in list or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a great use case for ternary operator:

```
user = input("userinput: ")
myList = ["Noah", "Mike"]

print("hello {}".format(user)) if (user in myList) else print("invalid")
```